# Get distinct values of one column

Tags: mysql

I have the below query,

```
SELECT v.pattern_id, 
       v.id, 
       v.pdb_id                                           AS viocardId, 
       p.pdb_id                                           AS PID, 
       s.vio_id                                           AS SiVioId, 
       r.date                                             AS orcdate, 
       s.created_date                                     AS sivcreateddate, 
       r.job_id, 
       r.maskset, 
       r.device, 
       d.tech_geometry, 
       r.layer, 
       r.layer_rev, 
       r.ptrf, 
       r.operation, 
       Concat_ws('_', d.tech_geometry, r.layer, p.pdb_id) AS techlayer 
FROM   orc_orcviolation v, 
       orc_orcpattern p, 
       siverify_siverifyverificationsite s, 
       orc_orccheck o, 
       orc_orcrecord r, 
       siverify_siverifyverificationdevice d 
WHERE  v.pattern_id = p.id 
       AND p.pdb_id = s.pattern_id 
       AND p.if_target = s.if_target 
       AND p.if_secure <> 1 
       AND s.create_status <> 5 
       AND v.check_id = o.id 
       AND o.record_id = r.id 
       AND d.id = s.si_device_id 
       AND r.maskset <> 'MT23RUN1' 
       AND r.maskset <> 'M25RUN3' 
       AND r.ptrf NOT LIKE '%PTRF-20251-%' 
       AND d.fab LIKE '%FAB 1%' 
       AND v.id > (SELECT v1.id 
                   FROM   orc_orcviolation v1, 
                          orc_orcpattern p1, 
                          siverify_siverifyverificationsite s1, 
                          orc_orccheck o1, 
                          orc_orcrecord r1, 
                          siverify_siverifyverificationdevice d1 
                   WHERE  v1.pattern_id = p1.id 
                          AND p1.pdb_id = s1.pattern_id 
                          AND p1.if_target = s1.if_target 
                          AND p1.if_secure <> 1 
                          AND s1.create_status <> 5 
                          AND v1.check_id = o1.id 
                          AND o1.record_id = r1.id 
                          AND d1.id = s1.si_device_id 
                          AND r1.maskset <> 'MT23RUN1' 
                          AND r1.maskset <> 'M25RUN3' 
                          AND r1.ptrf NOT LIKE '%PTRF-20251-%' 
                          AND d1.fab LIKE '%FAB 1%' 
                          AND v1.id = s1.vio_id 
                          AND s1.vio_id = s.vio_id) 
       AND r.date > s.created_date;
```

What I need is, I need to get distinct values just for the column r.job_id. My output for the above query looks like,

```
     pattern_id id  viocardId   PID SiVioId orcdate    sivcreateddate         job_id    maskset device  tech_geometry   layer   layer_rev   ptrf    operation   techlayer
    702627  2038025 8270564 4298455 1939970 4/16/2016 12:22 12/23/2015 1:14 442896  MPW2202 MPW2202_TEG1    0.022UM RX  AZ  PTRF-45862-2896 orc 0.022UM_RX_4298455
    702627  2038027 8270566 4298455 1939970 4/16/2016 12:22 12/23/2015 1:14 442896  MPW2202 MPW2202_TEG1    0.022UM RX  AZ  PTRF-45862-2896 orc 0.022UM_RX_4298455
    702627  2038029 8270568 4298455 1939970 4/16/2016 12:22 12/23/2015 1:14 442896  MPW2202 MPW2202_TEG1    0.022UM RX  AZ  PTRF-45862-2896 orc 0.022UM_RX_4298455
    702627  2112780 8425263 4298455 1939970 6/12/2016 4:08  12/23/2015 1:14 471956  ECLIPS4 ECLIPS4_SLM11   0.022UM RX  AZ  PTRF-45862-3249 orc 0.022UM_RX_4298455
    702627  2112783 8425266 4298455 1939970 6/12/2016 4:08  12/23/2015 1:14 471956  ECLIPS4 ECLIPS4_SLM11   0.022UM RX  AZ  PTRF-45862-3249 orc 0.022UM_RX_4298455
    702627  2112784 8425267 4298455 1939970 6/12/2016 4:08  12/23/2015 1:14 471956  ECLIPS4 ECLIPS4_SLM11   0.022UM RX  AZ  PTRF-45862-3249 orc 0.022UM_RX_4298455
    702627  2240805 8558618 4298455 1939970 8/27/2016 8:35  12/23/2015 1:14 504071  ECLIPS4 ECLIPS4_SLM11   0.022UM RX  AY  PTRF-45862-3610 orc 0.022UM_RX_4298455
    702627  2240807 8558620 4298455 1939970 8/27/2016 8:35  12/23/2015 1:14 504071  ECLIPS4 ECLIPS4_SLM11   0.022UM RX  AY  PTRF-45862-3610 orc 0.022UM_RX_4298455
```

In the above op, for the PID (4298455), we could see three job_ids(442896,471956,504071). I wanted to remove the repetition of job_ids and ideally my op should look like,

```
 pattern_id id  viocardId   PID SiVioId  orcdate     sivcreateddate    job_id   maskset device  tech_geometry   layer   layer_rev   ptrf    operation   techlayer
702627  2038025 8270564 4298455 1939970 4/16/2016 12:22 12/23/2015 1:14 442896  MPW2202 MPW2202_TEG1    0.022UM RX  AZ  PTRF-45862-2896 orc 0.022UM_RX_4298455
702627  2112780 8425263 4298455 1939970 6/12/2016 4:08  12/23/2015 1:14 471956  ECLIPS4 ECLIPS4_SLM11   0.022UM RX  AZ  PTRF-45862-3249 orc 0.022UM_RX_4298455
702627  2240805 8558618 4298455 1939970 8/27/2016 8:35  12/23/2015 1:14 504071  ECLIPS4 ECLIPS4_SLM11   0.022UM RX  AY  PTRF-45862-3610 orc 0.022UM_RX_4298455
```

I don't think creating a sub query just for distinct values of r.job_id would be a wise option as it might disturb the other parts of the query. Any ways to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The only two columns that differ values from one row to another from your original data are `id` and `viocardId` and on your wanted result you are getting the lesser values for both, since all data is the same but that two you could select all fields and those two aggregated with min. Something like: `select pattern_id, min(id),  min(viocardId),  PID, SiVioId... (all other columsn)...(rest of select).... group by (all fields but those two)` Try and see if it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to update your query

```
SELECT v.pattern_id, 
       MIN(v.id), 
       MIN(v.pdb_id)                                      AS viocardId, 
       p.pdb_id                                           AS PID, 
       s.vio_id                                           AS SiVioId, 
       r.date                                             AS orcdate, 
       s.created_date                                     AS sivcreateddate, 
       r.job_id, 
       r.maskset, 
       r.device, 
       d.tech_geometry, 
       r.layer, 
       r.layer_rev, 
       r.ptrf, 
       r.operation, 
       Concat_ws('_', d.tech_geometry, r.layer, p.pdb_id) AS techlayer 
FROM   orc_orcviolation v, 
       orc_orcpattern p, 
       siverify_siverifyverificationsite s, 
       orc_orccheck o, 
       orc_orcrecord r, 
       siverify_siverifyverificationdevice d 
WHERE  v.pattern_id = p.id 
       AND p.pdb_id = s.pattern_id 
       AND p.if_target = s.if_target 
       AND p.if_secure <> 1 
       AND s.create_status <> 5 
       AND v.check_id = o.id 
       AND o.record_id = r.id 
       AND d.id = s.si_device_id 
       AND r.maskset <> 'MT23RUN1' 
       AND r.maskset <> 'M25RUN3' 
       AND r.ptrf NOT LIKE '%PTRF-20251-%' 
       AND d.fab LIKE '%FAB 1%' 
       AND v.id > (SELECT v1.id 
                   FROM   orc_orcviolation v1, 
                          orc_orcpattern p1, 
                          siverify_siverifyverificationsite s1, 
                          orc_orccheck o1, 
                          orc_orcrecord r1, 
                          siverify_siverifyverificationdevice d1 
                   WHERE  v1.pattern_id = p1.id 
                          AND p1.pdb_id = s1.pattern_id 
                          AND p1.if_target = s1.if_target 
                          AND p1.if_secure <> 1 
                          AND s1.create_status <> 5 
                          AND v1.check_id = o1.id 
                          AND o1.record_id = r1.id 
                          AND d1.id = s1.si_device_id 
                          AND r1.maskset <> 'MT23RUN1' 
                          AND r1.maskset <> 'M25RUN3' 
                          AND r1.ptrf NOT LIKE '%PTRF-20251-%' 
                          AND d1.fab LIKE '%FAB 1%' 
                          AND v1.id = s1.vio_id 
                          AND s1.vio_id = s.vio_id) 
       AND r.date > s.created_date;
GROUP BY 
       v.pattern_id, 
       PID, 
       SiVioId, 
       orcdate, 
       sivcreateddate, 
       r.job_id, 
       r.maskset, 
       r.device, 
       d.tech_geometry, 
       r.layer, 
       r.layer_rev, 
       r.ptrf, 
       r.operation, 
       techlayer
```